# root password not working after changing my.ini

Tags: mysql

i forgot my root password....
then i stopped  mysql server and restarted it with **skip-grant-tables**;
i changed the root password by

```
mysql>update mysql.user set password='12345' where user='root';
mysql> select user,password from mysql.user;
```

i got this::::

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | password                                  |
+------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | 12345                                     |
| waza | *8041F6A85F9698257ABF11AB449CC48FE6093750 |
| pma  |                                           |
| puru | *4538301D3121D4617B1EDE9CFAFDFEB70AFF9E08 |
+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

now i stopped mysql server and changed my.ini and removed skip-grant-tables;
restarted the mysql server:::
tried to login on command line with the password 12345
and it s not logging in

```
C:\Users\hp-pc>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

what should i do????

Comment: I would generally advise against directly running an UPDATE against the mysql.user table. Your best bet would be to use `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');`

Comment: thanx it works.....
but what should i do if i wish to see the passwords like *8041F6A85F9698257ABF11AB449CC48FE6093750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to stop mysqld and restart it with the **--skip-grant-tables** option. 
This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Make sure you're **FLUSHING PRIVILEGES** after the pw change

[MySQL Documentation on Resetting Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: using **--skip-grant-tables** i cant grant privilages to user.....
    `mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by  'root_password';`
`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this sta
tement`
mysql>

Comment: When the server reloads the grant tables, privileges for each existing client connection are affected as follows:
Table and column privilege changes take effect with the client's next request.
Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client executes a USE db_name statement.
Note
Client applications may cache the database name; thus, this effect may not be visible to them without actually changing to a different database or flushing the privileges.